# How can I turn an edge into a part of circle?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

[image: I want to turn this edge into a circle wi]

Hello!

I was working on some helmet model, when I had a problem. I need to turn this edge into an arc of circle, like in the following picture. Is there a way to do it? Bevel doesn't seem to work too well.

[image: Helmet I'm trying to replicate]

Answer (score 3):

Create this shape, select these edges:

[image]

Bevel:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to **preferences** and enable an add-on called  **edit mesh tools**.   Select the edges first.  Now you can use something called the **edge roundifier** to create a new edge like the one you are describing.

Check **remove: edges** to delete them without affecting many additional faces or vertices.

Once you have the curves you want you can fill or **bridge Edge loop** missing faces[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEe5A.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEe5A.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, when I try to press Arc loops, I get this error. Is thi/s normal? Python: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\mesh_tools\mesh_edge_roundifier.py", line 625, in execute self.roundifyEdges(scaledEdges, parameters, bm, mesh) File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\mesh_tools\mesh_edge_roundifier.py", line 726, in roundifyEdges self.connectArcsTogether(arcs, bm, mesh, parameters) File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\add

Comment: No, I haven't had that trouble.  I can suggest another way of doing it though. I'll add one other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add edge loops.  This gives you more points to work with.  To do this, you select the object, and go into edit mode.  Select the mesh and hold down control+R while scrolling your middle mouse button.

[[image]

You can check on proportional editing and sphere.

Then drag two points down, until you get the shape you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the reference image it appears to me that these parts need to be rounded (my object is a bit shorter than the one in the picture):

[image: reference comparison]

This is how I would do it, looks like a lot of steps maybe I explained it too detailed:

1. Select those 4 top edges, right-click and choose *Subdivide* from the context menu. This creates two new edges from the front to the back.

[image: subdivide top edges]

2. In order to get the top more arc-shaped, the top needs to be pushed in a little. To do that, select the two newly created edges.

[image: select new edges]

3. Now move them down on the Z axis by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. If the bend doesn't look sharp enough, eventually also scale it in a little (which in this example would mean on the X axis) by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image: push edges in]

4. Now use the bevel tool <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to round off the edges, use the scrollwheel to create more or less segments to smoothen the arc. If the arc is too flat, maybe abort the action and go back to step 3. to push the edges further down and/or inwards.

[image: bevel tool 1]

5. Now select those two middle edges on the side. These need to be rounded as well.

[image: select middle edges]

6. These will beveled, too.

[image: bevel tool 2]

7. Now the front and back faces look a bit messed up. What I did to clean it up or simplify the geometry so that it looks more like the original (but of course this is optional, it depends a lot on what you are further going to do with the mesh): I enter *Face Select* mode, select some faces, press <kbd>F</kbd> to merge them to a single face.

[image: merge faces]

8. I repeat that for other areas on the front and back until I have a geometry I like.

[image: merge more faces]

9. Now I switch back to *Edge Select* mode and select the two corner faces at the bottom of the object.

[image: select corners]

10. And they will also be beveled. Now the shape of the object resembles the one in the reference picture.

[image: bevel tool 3]

Answer (score 0):

I create a circle with a big radius. Then take the arc I need, delete the other vertices so only this arc is here again. I delete the previous top edges, merge the ends of the arc and the top vertices, extrude to the object width, then create faces.
[I kinda did it like this video at 0:58](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlX-TCUsOhg)

Comment: That is good headway.  You can sometimes use the boolean modifier and union, to join some objects if that helps.

Comment: I think I may have understood from the title.  Your question is more about joining two objects.

Comment: I wanted to do what you did in the first answer you sent me. Just willing to make the face appear rounder.